# Hovercard not displaying in knockoutJS with-binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js

I got this hover card and I want to display it inside a sub-menu. It works int the header, but somehow the hover effect does not kick in when inside the sub-menu "with:$root.chosenMenu"-bindings.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span class="previewCard">    
        <label class="hovercardName" data-bind="text: displayName"></label>
        <span class="hovercardDetails">     
            <span data-bind="text: miniBio"></span>.<br/>
            <a data-bind="attr: { href: webpage, title: webpage }, text: webpage">My blog</a>
        </span>
    </span> 
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="wysClear wysLeft buttonRow">
        <a href="#pid1" data-bind="click: function(){$root.chosenMenu('a');return false;}">Panel A</a>
        <a href="#pid2" data-bind="click: function(){$root.chosenMenu('b');return false;}">Panel B</a>
    </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div data-bind="with: $root.chosenMenu">
    <div id="pid1" data-bind="visible: $root.chosenMenu() === 'a'">
        panel A: <br/><br/>
        <span class="previewCard">    
            <label class="hovercardName" data-bind="text: $root.displayName"></label>
            <span class="hovercardDetails">     
                <span data-bind="text: $root.miniBio"></span>.<br/>
                <a data-bind="attr: { href: $root.webpage, title: $root.webpage }, text: $root.webpage">My blog</a>
            </span>
        </span> 
    </div>
    <div id="pid2" data-bind="visible: $root.chosenMenu() === 'b'">
        panel B: <br/><br/>
        <span class="previewCard">    
            <label class="hovercardName" data-bind="text: $root.displayName"></label>
            <span class="hovercardDetails">     
                <span data-bind="text: $root.miniBio"></span>.<br/>
                <a data-bind="attr: { href: $root.webpage, title: $root.webpage }, text: $root.webpage">My blog</a>
            </span>
        </span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.chosenMenu = ko.observable();
    self.displayName = ko.observable("Asle G");
    self.miniBio = ko.observable("Everywhere we go - there you are!");
    self.webpage = ko.observable("http://blog.a-changing.com")
};

ko.applyBindings( new viewModel() );

// hovercard
$(".previewCard").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".hovercardDetails").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".hovercardDetails").stop(true, true).fadeOut();
});
```

CSS:

```
.previewCard {
    position:relative;            
}
.hovercardName {    
    font-weight:bold;    
    position:relative;    
    z-index:100; /*greater than details, to still appear in card*/
}
.hovercardDetails {            
    background:#fff ;    
    border:solid 1px #ddd;      
    position:absolute ;
    width:300px;
    left:-10px;
    top:-10px;
    z-index:50; /*less than name*/
    padding:2em 10px 10px; /*leave enough padding on top for the name*/   
    display:none;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/jb6b61oh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a classical jQuery problem: event handlers are only attached to elements that *exist* at the time.

This attaches the `hover` (mouseenter/mouseleave) event handlers to the only `.previewCard` there is:

```
$(".previewCard").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".hovercardDetails").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".hovercardDetails").stop(true, true).fadeOut();
});
```

But if knockout creates a few more dynamically, they won't have any event handlers. So you have to *delegate* event handling to a node that's higher in the hierarchy.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".previewCard", function() {
    $(this).find(".hovercardDetails").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
}).on("mouseleave", ".previewCard", function() {
    $(this).find(".hovercardDetails").stop(true, true).fadeOut();
});
```

---

That's still not a very *clean* way to solve the problem. Why not create a hovercard binding handler and get rid entirely of the jQuery code in your view model?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.hovercard = {
    init: function (element) {
        $(element).hover(function() {
            $(this).find(".hovercardDetails").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
        }, function() {
            $(this).find(".hovercardDetails").stop(true, true).fadeOut();
        });
    }
};
```

Used as:

```
<span class="previewCard" data-bind="hovercard: true">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jb6b61oh/6/

Comment: BTW, in my css the ,hovercardDetails.width=300px. If It´s within a narrower <div>, say 200px, is there a way to make it float on top without causing an overflow-situation and trigging scrollbars?

Comment: That's a separate question. ;) There are only so many values for position and overflow, experimenting a little should get you there.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @Tomalak! Probably will post a new question on this as I struggle with making this work and keeping an overflow-y:auto on my list.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem was in your `with` binding. You're setting the context for one observable which at the time is undefined and therefore any descendant elements are removed. See [knockout docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html#example-2):

> The with binding will dynamically add or remove descendant elements depending on whether the associated value is null/undefined or not``

That means that at the time jQuery runs, your elements aren't in the DOM so they are not bound to the hover event. So, if you change this:

```
data-bind="with: $root.chosenMenu">
```

to this:

```
<div data-bind="with: $root">
```

Your issue is fixed. That said, you really should use a custom binding handler for this.

```js
viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.chosenMenu = ko.observable();
    self.displayName = ko.observable("Asle G");
    self.miniBio = ko.observable("Everywhere we go - there you are!");
    self.webpage = ko.observable("http://blog.a-changing.com")
};

ko.applyBindings( new viewModel() );

// hovercard
$(".previewCard").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".hovercardDetails").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".hovercardDetails").stop(true, true).fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.previewCard {
    position:relative;            
}
.hovercardName {    
    font-weight:bold;    
    position:relative;    
    z-index:100; /*greater than details, to still appear in card*/
}
.hovercardDetails {            
    background:#fff ;    
    border:solid 1px #ddd;      
    position:absolute ;
    width:300px;
    left:-10px;
    top:-10px;
    z-index:50; /*less than name*/
    padding:2em 10px 10px; /*leave enough padding on top for the name*/   
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span class="previewCard">    
        <label class="hovercardName" data-bind="text: displayName"></label>
        <span class="hovercardDetails">     
            <span data-bind="text: miniBio"></span>.<br/>
            <a data-bind="attr: { href: webpage, title: webpage }, text: webpage">My blog</a>
        </span>
    </span> 
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="wysClear wysLeft buttonRow">
        <a href="#pid1" data-bind="click: function(){$root.chosenMenu('a');return false;}">Panel A</a>
        <a href="#pid2" data-bind="click: function(){$root.chosenMenu('b');return false;}">Panel B</a>
    </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div data-bind="with: $root">
    <div id="pid1" data-bind="visible: chosenMenu() === 'a'">
        panel A: <br/><br/>
        <span class="previewCard">    
            <label class="hovercardName" data-bind="text: displayName"></label>
            <span class="hovercardDetails">     
                <span data-bind="text: miniBio"></span>.<br/>
                <a data-bind="attr: { href: webpage, title: webpage }, text: webpage">My blog</a>
            </span>
        </span> 
    </div>
    <div id="pid2" data-bind="visible: chosenMenu() === 'b'">
        panel B: <br/><br/>
        <span class="previewCard">    
            <label class="hovercardName" data-bind="text: displayName"></label>
            <span class="hovercardDetails">     
                <span data-bind="text: miniBio"></span>.<br/>
                <a data-bind="attr: { href: webpage, title: webpage }, text: webpage">My blog</a>
            </span>
        </span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, these are brilliant answers making me learn a lot. Thanks guys!